# CSS not working or changing image size

Tags: html, css

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my CSS [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/3pr2g8sb/)

Code:

```css
#contact {
  height: 50%;
  length: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact">
  <a href="http://amazon.com/">`
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/GMldHhn.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Either I'm blind or I totally forgot CSS, but this has to be the most simple CSS, yet it doesn't work.  The image size is not reduced at all.  It's not affected a tall.  Even if I change the `50%` to `10px` it still doesn't do anything.  And I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Do you mean `width:50%` instead of `length:50%`?

Answer (score 5):

There is **no** `length` property, instead use `width` and you need to apply the properties to `img` not the (grand)parent div `contact`

#### Snippet

```css
#contact img {
 height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="original">
  <a href="http://amazon.com/">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/GMldHhn.jpg" />
  </a>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="contact">
  <a href="http://amazon.com/">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/GMldHhn.jpg" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no`length` in CSS you use width that is probably your problem use this code:

```
#contact img {
   height: 50%;
   width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'm blind....this one totally escaped me.  I'm so knee deep in code, I get clouded sometimes.  Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: @steve02a the quick reply really? was only 3 minutes after my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

the thing is you shoud give your expecting `width` and `height` of the image to your `div`, that holds your image.after that you should give the `width` and `height` for your `img` as `width:100%`, 'height:100%'.this is the full code for you.hope this will help.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Image</title>
<style>
  body{
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
  }

  div#contact
  {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    
  }

  div#contact img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px black;
    margin: 2%;
  }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="contact">
  <a href="http://amazon.com/">`
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/GMldHhn.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```css
#contact {
  height: 10%;
  width: 10%;
}

#img {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact">
  <a href="http://amazon.com/">`
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/GMldHhn.jpg" id="img" />
    </a>
</div>
```